# How to make a close button for a Flash banner ad with Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, ads

I am working on a Flash banner ad built with Actionscript 3. It will be embedded into web pages.

The ad needs to have a close button. When the user clicks the button the ad should disappear.

This needs to be done entirely in the banner, as we have no control over the webpages where it will be embedded.

In Actionscript 2 I used to do this by running this code when the user clicked the button:

```
unloadMovie(this);
```

This seems to no longer work in Actionscript 3. What can I do to achieve this functionality in AS3?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You probably have a main symbol containing everything else, if so, you can stop all timelines and remove the main container from the display list

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza That does indeed make the banner disappear. However the flash <object> remains over the page in full size and it blocks user interaction with what is underneath. The user can't select text from under it, CSS hover effects don't trigger, etc. This didn't happen with unloadMovie() in AS2.

Comment: I see. Do you have control over the html code used to embed your swf on a page ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza No, as I said we have no control over the webpages where it will be embedded. I've been doing a lot of googling and so far have found nothing. There are ways to do it if the website uses an adserver that has support for something like this. In that case you just use ExternalInterface.call() to call a Javascipt function that closes the ad.

Comment: Regarding ExternalInterface, that's exactly what I was thinking. Check out [Zeh](http://zehfernando.com/2011/getting-the-swfs-html-objectembed-id-from-within-the-flash-movie-itself/)'s blog post. Perhaps you can fetch the element/object id/name from within the swf and use use the dom to remove the swf ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Thanks, I didn't think that was possible. Zeh's getSWFObjectName() function didn't seem to work as intended (specifically the `objects[i][__randomFunction]` part). So I modified it a bit. You can see the result here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9659181

It works if the html object has an ID. Tested in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE 11,9,8,7.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza If you'll post it as an aswer I'd love to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For documentation purposes, here are the conclusions Andreyu  and I reached regarding the issue: unloading/removing a swf file from within the swf to allow users access to the elements under the swf.

One option is to use [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to inject js code to:

1. get the id/name of the swf as registered with the DOM
2. remove the swf element from the DOM using the found id/name

In terms of code, this is using a technique described on [Zeh Fernando's blog](http://zehfernando.com/2011/getting-the-swfs-html-objectembed-id-from-within-the-flash-movie-itself/)
as modified by Andreyu to include the DOM element removal:

```
// Based on work by Zeh Fernando: http://zehfernando.com/2011/getting-the-swfs-html-objectembed-id-from-within-the-flash-movie-itself/

function getSWFObjectName(): String {
    // Returns the SWF's object name for getElementById

    // Based on https://github.com/millermedeiros/Hasher_AS3_helper/blob/master/dev/src/org/osflash/hasher/Hasher.as

    var js:XML;
    js = <script><![CDATA[
        function(__randomFunction) {
            var check = function(objects){

                    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++){
                        if (typeof(eval("objects["+i+"]." + __randomFunction)) != undefined) {
                            return objects[i].id;
                        }
                    }
                    return undefined;
                };

                return check(document.getElementsByTagName("object")) || check(document.getElementsByTagName("embed"));
        }
    ]]></script>;

    var __randomFunction:String = "checkFunction_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999); // Something random just so it's safer

    ExternalInterface.addCallback(__randomFunction, getSWFObjectName); // The second parameter can be anything, just passing a function that exists

    return ExternalInterface.call(js, __randomFunction);
}

// Function to remove the SWF from the webpage
function destroyEverything(event:MouseEvent): void {

    var js:XML;
    js = <script><![CDATA[
        function(__SWFContext) {

            var element = document.getElementById(__SWFContext);
            element.parentNode.removeChild(element);

        }
    ]]></script>;


    ExternalInterface.call(js, getSWFObjectName());
}


// Add function to click event of button
close_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, destroyEverything);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `unloadMovie` was enough for you, you could simply remove everything from the stage:

```
//In button click handler, call "removeEverything" function
//function onClickClose(e:MouseEvent):void{
//    removeEverything()
//}
//As a result you will get empty stage

function removeEverything():void {
    while (stage.numChildren) {
        stage.removeChildAt(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll copy my comment from above, because the effect is identical: That does indeed make the banner disappear. However the flash <object> remains over the page in full size and it blocks user interaction with what is underneath. The user can't select text from under it, CSS hover effects don't trigger, etc. This didn't happen with unloadMovie() in AS2.